# Would a classic full time armageddon tiebreaker be balanced?

Tags: draw, time-control

I think that classic chess and rapid chess are two quite different kinds of sport. The classic chess title was undecided this year 2018.

Why not use the armageddon rule, that black wins if tied in exchange for a white time advantage, in a classic format? Say for example normal classic time rules for white, but in total only 100 minutes with no increment per move and no additional time after move 40 for black. Could something like that be fair or is it too easy for black to force a drawing position during the first 40 moves? Is armageddon all about blunders under time pressure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classical Time Control Armageddon?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/28408/classical-time-control-armageddon)

Comment: If question A is later followed by question then B can be a duplicate of A but not vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

That wouldn't make any sense. In a long game between two 2800+ players, a draw is always very likely. Carlsen and Caruana understand exactly how to steer a game to a draw.

Whoever gets Black would have a winning advantage before the game even started.

Comment: What amount of time handicap would you bid black to have, in order to accept playing white with full classic time?

Comment: None.  Games are far too long as it is.  Giving more time just makes it more boring.  Play more games at faster time controls.  Two games at a time WB for each, and keep playing pairs of games until someone wins a match.  Keep lowering the total time for the game if there is still a problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense if there's an auction? The 2010 USCC won by Gata Kamsky was classical in the sense that it had an armageddon game with a base time of 60 minutes and even had increment. But for some reason it is considered rapid. Is this news to you - that it actually happened already?