# In armageddon bidding, what happens if the bid is drawn?

Tags: tournament, statistics, time-control, armageddon

Re [armageddon](https://www.chess.com/terms/armageddon-chess), there is sometimes bidding ("how much time they're willing to give up to play with their desired color") instead of pre-determined 5min vs 4min.

What happens if the bid is drawn?

Comment: Why the recent obsession with Armageddon bidding?

Comment: @David because of the Airthings Masters that just happened? especially with Magnus' "soul read" I guess a lot of people suddenly found it more entertaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the rules being used. A likely scenario is that an additional tie-break would be used.

For example, in the regulations for the [2016 US Championships](https://www.uschesschamps.com/information-2016-us-championship/regulations):

> If both Players bid exactly the same amount of time, the Chief Arbiter will flip a coin to determine who shall choose their color.

Comment: A more elegant solution (that I have not yet seen used though) would be to simply
force one of the players to bid an odd number of seconds and the other an even, 
preventing a drawn bid in the first place.

Comment: Well, that distinguishes the players a priori, so is less elegant in that way.