# When was there a classical armageddon?

Tags: time-control, armageddon

Armageddon is usually rapid/blitz/bullet. What tournaments used classical armageddon for tiebreaker?

Btw classical here of course means is [60min+ (for white)](https://%20https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41605/what-are-examples-of-tournaments-games-60-minutes-to-below-120-minutes-and-how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ff questions, seemingly no one else knew (including myself) that there was already a classical armageddon game in the [2010 US chess championship won by Gata Kamsky](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44972/why-is-the-2010-uscc-armageddon-between-gata-kamsky-yury-shulman-considered-ra), but I guess it depends on how you [define 'classical'](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41605/what-are-examples-of-tournaments-games-60-minutes-to-below-120-minutes-and-how).

1. [Would a classic full time armageddon tiebreaker be balanced?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23160/would-a-classic-full-time-armageddon-tiebreaker-be-balanced)
2. [Classical Time Control Armageddon?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/28408/classical-time-control-armageddon)